# operator T&() or operator T()?

Tags: c++, reference, conversion-operator

In defining a conversion operator, is there any advantage of defining

```
operator T() const;
```

over

```
operator T&();
operator const T&() const;
```

Assuming that I'm not concerned in potential performance gain in returning a value instead of a reference.

Comment: `operator T&();` is not like the others. Presumably, it'd return a reference to the class member; the caller would then be able to modify said member. The other two flavors don't allow that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach is definitely better.

With the first approach the calling code is *required* to make a copy of the returned object, which could be expensive.

With the second approach the calling code has the option of making or not making a copy.

When you are responsible for a class/library, you don't want to be responsible for performance bottlenecks for which they are no workarounds.

One major drawback of the second approach is that the calling code could be be left with a dangling pointer/reference. In order to help your users you'll have to clearly document how long the returned references are valid. Hopefully your users will take heed and do the right thing.

Comment: On the other hand, the second one could be used to create a dangling reference. So there are pros and cons to each.

Comment: @M.M The user should be aware of that whenever he/she creates a reference or pointer. This is not specific to the case posed in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on the situation. The first approach returns a new object that can be modified without altering the original object. The second approach returns a reference to an existing object. If you change this object, you will also change the original object.

Which one is the right for you to decide; there is no general advantage.

Comment: If the object is not expected to be modified, the user should `const` qualify it. So, if you don't want to modify the original object, make a copy instead.

Comment: @Lingxi: why are you asking a question then trying to tell several of the people answering what the answer should be?  Ask and *listen*, or feel free to post your own answer and let other readers up/down-vote it on its merits... that's the SO way ;-p.

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for mentioning it to me. I will keep that in mind, and do the right thing next time :-)